# Split Polygon in one layer based on boundaries in second layer

Tags: qgis, polygon, layers, references, st-split

I have two different polygon layers, 1 and 2. Now i want to split polygons in layer 1 taking reference from polygons in layer 2. Is it possible in qgis???? Please find attached image as reference layer 1 in red colur and layer 2 is in black.

[image]

Comment: Try the ["Union"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#union)

Comment: and then ["Dissolve"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorgeoprocessing.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the processing toolbox search for `Polygons to lines` and convert Layer 2 into lines, then search again for `Split with lines`, use the lines that you have created to split Layer 1.